# MongoDB insert into Json array using nodeJS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to keep adding appointments to this array inside of a JSON object. My JSON object looks like the following ...

```
{"_id": "travis@hotmail.com","appointment": [{"date": "12/16/2015", "time": "8:40:44pm"}]}
```

My code doesn't show an error in the git shell, but it doesn't add the item to the array, I have tried `db.findById(..),.insert()` and other methods and couldn't make them to work, but here's my code:

```
var SchemaApp = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id    : String,
        appointment:[{
            date: String,
            time: String
        }]          
    });
var appointments = mongoose.model('appointment', SchemaApp);
app.post('/makeApp',function(req,res){
  var patient = req.body.appPatient;
  var date = req.body.dateApp;
  var hour = req.body.hour;
  var minutes = req.body.minutes;
  var time = hour+":"+minutes;
  appointments.update(
    {"_id": patient},
    {"$push":{
            "appointment":{
                "date": date,
                "time": time
            }
        }
    }                   
 );
 res.redirect("/admin");
);
```

if I print to the console the patient,date and time they show perfectly fine.

Comment: What is are the values of the variables -  `appointments` and `patient`? can you double check.

Comment: @BatScream var appointments = mongoose.model('appointments', SchemaApp); and patient when I console.log it gives me the email

Comment: can you change `mongoose.model('appointments', SchemaApp)` to `mongoose.model('appointment', SchemaApp)` and try again. Use `singular` schema names. `mongoose` by default searches for a collection denoted by its `plural`(adding an `s` to it) form.

Comment: @BatScream it didn't work. I have updated my my post so you can see my SchemaApp and the mongoose.model

Comment: What is your `mongodb` collection name?

Comment: Collection: appointments. That's why I had it in plural inside of the mongoose.model

Comment: so, it should be `appointment` without the `s` when you define it in mongoose.

Comment: @BatScream  
I have edited my collection name to "appointment" and made sure the mongoose.model('appointment', SchemaApp) is like you told me, but still doesn't work

Comment: can you change the _id    : String, in schema to patientid : String and try the same thing in update instead of _id to patientid.

Comment: @KethaKavya didn't work... any other suggestion?